# How to pass a query result to a second query in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, pymongo

My target was to run a query that involves text search. Below is my attempt:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
REMOTE_MONGO_URL = ""

mongo_connection = MongoClient(REMOTE_MONGO_URL)

xml_db = mongo_connection.some_string.some_other_string

#pprint(xml_db.index_information())


a = xml_db.find(
    {
        "source": "winterfell",
            'expiration_date': {
                '$gte': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            },

        "$text": {
                '$search': "ned cat john arya sansa"
            }
    },
    #hint='red_wedding'
)

print(a.count())
```

Initially, when I run the query, it just runs for infinite time, and I got the feeling that it's not using the proper index. So, I tried to impose the index with `$hint`. However, it fails with the message that I can't use `$text` and `$hint` together.

So, my plan is to first perform the initial query without text search (so that I can use `$hint` on it), and run the second query of text search on the result of first query. How can I do it?